# how to set hidden fields in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to web programming and ruby on rails. are hidden fields used only within a form element, or can you use them without the form element?

```
   <input id="hiddenId" name="hiddenId" type="hidden" value="1"/>
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of a hidden input field outside a form?

Comment: Are you asking how to set it or why or where?...

Comment: can it be used , if there is not a form element in the html page?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this helper tag in your .html.erb. It's usually used like a form element.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :field_name, 'value' %>
```

[more details here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag)